# How can I get maximum value from Firebase in my React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

I want to get data having max value. I have an auction app where people can bid so I want to find the highest value to award that product to max value. What are the ways for it?

Answer (score 2):

In your database's rules make the list of bids be indexed on the price. Something like:

```
"bids": {
      ".indexOn": "price"
}
```

Then in your code you would use a query to only fetch 1 entry from an item's bids:

```
ref.orderByChild("bids").limitToFirst(1).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
```

Which should give you the highest bid, if it gives you the lowest then just switch `limitToFirst` to `limitToLast`.